# How do I say every element of $X$ is greater than every element of $Y$?

Tags: notation, terminology

What's the easiest accepted way to write every element of $X$ is greater than every element of $Y$?

Can I just say $X>Y$,

or do I need to say $\min{X}>\max{Y}$,

or even $x>y\quad\forall x\in X, y\in Y$?

Comment: It's the last one, but this only makes sense if $X\subset Z$ and $Y\subset Z$ for some ordered set $Z$.

Comment: You cannot use the second one because min and/or max need not exist. However, if you need the notation repeatedly, you may want to *define* $X>Y$ as a shorthand for $\forall x\in X, y\in Y\colon x>y$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you take infimum and supremum? But those can be equal and still have this condition

Comment: @Pieter21 But there are might not exist supremum of $Y$ and/or infimun of $X$.

Comment: @Masacroso What if $X=\{a,b\}$, $Y=\{c,d\}$, and the order is given by $c<a$, $c<b$, $d<a$, $d<b$. Every element of $X$ is greater than every element of $Y$. Yet, there is no supremum of $Y$ or infimum of $X$. Maybe you mean there is an infimum of $X$ (in $X \cup Y$) iff there is a supremum of $Y$? I think I'm not missing anything...

Comment: @amrsa yes, you are right. I assumed the Op was talking about subset of the real line. For other setups clearly the notion of $\sup$ and $\inf$ can be maningless.

Comment: I think that, out of the alternatives you presented, one which is accepted in order theory is the use of the operators $^l$ and $^u$ used in the Dedekind-MacNeille completion. Here $X^l$ stands for lower bounds of $X$ and $Y^u$ for upper bounds of $Y$. So you could say $X \subseteq Y^u$ or equivalently, $Y \subseteq X^l$ (it is a Galois connection). But this notation is, perhaps, also not that convenient...

Comment: I'll probably say $$\min_{x\in X} x \gt \max_{y\in Y} y$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I know this is a simple question and you may feel it's rep too easily earned but this site is for mathematicians of all levels and others will need this question answered. If you want to summarise your comments in an answer I can accept.